# Agrupación de datos en una sola casilla en una consulta a varias tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo tres tablas: articles, categories y articles_categories (que es una tabla de relación entre las tablas articles y categories, porque un articulo puede tener varias categorías y una categoría puede tener muchos artículos)

[image: Captura de pantalla del diagrama entidad relación (phpmyadmin): https://i.imgur.com/rpANVSs.png]
*Captura de pantalla del diagrama entidad relación (phpmyadmin)*

Quiero hacer una consulta que me muestre la información de todos los artículos, con un campo que me indique todas sus categorías.

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT
    articles.*,
    categories.name AS categoria, categories.id AS categoria_id
FROM articles_categories
LEFT JOIN articles ON articles_categories.article_id = articles.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON articles_categories.category_id = categories.id
ORDER BY articles.id;
```

[image: Captura de pantalla del resultado de la consulta anterior: https://i.imgur.com/swWDgpU.png]
*Captura de pantalla del resultado de la consulta anterior*

La consulta anterior me devuelve la información que quiero, pero no consigo agrupar las categorias para no tener filas de articulos repetidos.. ¿cómo podría agrupar la consulta de categorias?

Es decir, por ejemplo en el artículo 7 que tiene tres categorias. En vez de 3 filas, cada una con su categoría, necesitaría que estuviera en una sola línea con un campo que incluya las 3 categorías que tiene. ¿Cómo debería hacer esto?

Muchas gracias

Comment: [Pregunta](/q/478151) muy MUY similar. Por cierto, PHPMyAdmin es una herramienta: el motor de base de datos que tienes podría ser o MySQL o MariaDB.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon todas las imagenes que tienes de ejemplo en tu misma pregunta, no uses hipervinculos, es mas comodo que todo este en la misma pregunta

Comment: @padaleiana muchas gracias! Con la función GROUP_CONCAT que se muestra en esa pregunta obtengo lo que quiero. Igualmente he arreglado mi pregunta  :) ¿Qué debería hacer con la pregunta? Publico la solución?

Comment: @itaca9 si publica la solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los comentarios de la pregunta @padaleiana ha enlazado una pregunta que trata una situación similar.

La solución a mi consulta es utilizar la función `GROUP_CONCAT`, y con ella ya es posible utilizar la cláusula `GROUP BY` para agrupar los resultados por artículo y tener la información de todas las categorías.

La consulta resultante es:

```
SELECT
   articles.*,
   GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name) AS categorias
FROM articles_categories
LEFT JOIN articles ON articles_categories.article_id = articles.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON articles_categories.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY articles.id
ORDER BY articles.id;
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/5ujc4tN.png]
*Captura de pantalla del resultado de la consulta anterior*

Comment: Espero hayas dado +1 a la respuesta original :)

Comment: Sí, lo he hecho :)

Comment: Y tampoco olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.